# For EditText, how can I force user (or accept) only certain strings, without using spinner?

Tags: android

I do not want to use spinner since it is takes too much space.
How can I limit user to enter text that is contained in my string array such as {"Celery", "Carrot", "Apple"}?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use list dialog is similar to spinner but it takes less space.Also make the editable of the edittext is false. So that it will accept only those values which are there in string array.

Comment: It appears, setting android:editable to false does not allow user to see the choices. Besides android:editable is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find your answer useful.